# mysql select next and previous record order by alpha character

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, window-functions

I have a database table with multiples companies profiles, I want to display each company profile with previous and next companies link. If current company name **'D'** then previous company will be **'C'** and next company **'E'**. Please help me for this.

[image]

```
current ->  select * from `sample` where id = 4; value is D

previous - > select * from `sample` where (need to fetch record with value c ) limit 1

next - > select * from `sample` where (need to fetch record with value e ) limit 1
```

Comment: Please include sample data.

Comment: Use `LAG`/`LEAD` functions over `ORDER BY value`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen question updated

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: 10.4.13-MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with window functions `LAG()` and `LEAD()`.

If you want the result in 1 row:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
         LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY value) prev_id,
         LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY value) next_id
  FROM tablename         
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE value = 'd'
```

Result:

```
> id | value | prev_id | next_id
> -: | :---- | ------: | ------:
>  4 | d     |      11 |      12
```

Or if you want 2 rows:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
         LAG(value) OVER (ORDER BY value) prev_value,
         LEAD(value) OVER (ORDER BY value) next_value
  FROM tablename         
)
SELECT id, value
FROM cte
WHERE 'd' IN (prev_value, next_value)
```

Result:

```
> id | value
> -: | :----
> 11 | c    
> 12 | e
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=481407811b8d9d76e4891b2341c058b7).